# How to combine two structured ArrayType columns grouped by one of the structure fields into a third column with a different structure in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am quite a novice in Spark but I'm trying to do something that feels easy but turns out the syntax is complex.

I have a one-row data set and I am trying to combine two structured arrayType columns into a third one. Let's say I have the following car-related single-row data table(the first two columns are irrelevant, but they exist if that makes any difference):

```
+--+--+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|C1|C2| carColor                                 | carPrice                      |
+--+--+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1|A |[{type: BMW, color: red, owner: Alice},   | [{type: Toyota, price: 30000},|
|  |  | {type: Ford, color: blue, owner: Bob},   |  {type: BMW, price: 50000}]   |
|  |  | {type: Honda, color: pink, owner: Chuck}]|                               |
+--+--+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I am trying to transform it by combining the columns carColor (which is an array whose items are structured like {type, color, owner}) and carPrice (an array of {type, price}) into a new column 'cars' which groupes the data by car type and only takes the color and the price (not the owner). See below:

```
+--+--+--------------------------------------------+
|C1|C2| cars                                       |
+--+--+--------------------------------------------+
| 1|A |[{type: BMW, color: red, price: 50000},     |
|  |  | {type: Ford, color: blue, price: 0},       |
|  |  | {type: Honda, color: pink, price: 0},      |
|  |  | {type: Toyota, color: null, price: 30000}] |
+--+--+--------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the carColor and carPrice arrays are not necessarily in the same order, and there can be different car types in each column. I want all the distinct car types in the end result, with the "missing data" fields set to null/0.

This last requirement is the tricky one for me. Right now I have something like the below code but it only works if the car types are the same and in the same order in both input columns. I think I need to include groupBy somewhere, or some form of conditional combination statement, but I can't figure out the SparkSQL syntax for it.

```
    private static Dataset<Row> addCars(Dataset<Row> dataset) {
        return dataset.select(col("C1"), col("C2"), col("carColor"), col("carPrice"))
            .withColumn("cars", struct(expr(
                "transform(arrays_zip(carColor, carPrice), x -> struct(x.carColor.type as type, x.carColor.color as color, x.carPrice.price as price")));
    }
```

Comment: Are there more rows? And if so, what would that mean?

Comment: @thebluephantom thanks for your interest! It's only ever one row at a time that I'm handling. It's a spark streaming job that waits for data to arrive, one row of it once in a while, and then processes it.

Comment: @antemerid Are you using AWS or Azure databricks?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula AWS

Comment: Structured streaming or streaming?

Comment: Using structured streaming @thebluephantom

Comment: Java, not common.

Comment: Yeah, I've had a difficult time finding similar examples of what I want to do, and even more difficult in Java.

Comment: I think, without looking at Str Str limitations you need to explode both cols, join and collect. Can you set the defs in scala for us to try and would you accept a scala answer?